# What are the critical files in ~/.gnupg

Tags: gnupg

Over the years, quite a lot of files have accumulated in my ~/.gnupg directory:

```
~/.gnupg$ tree -a
.
├── crls.d
│   └── DIR.txt
├── gpg-agent.conf
├── gpg.conf
├── .gpg-v21-migrated
├── private-keys-v1.d
│   └── XXX-XXX.key    # several .key-files are here
├── pubring.gpg
├── pubring.kbx
├── random_seed
└── trustdb.gpg
```

Does anyone know how to find out what each file is for, so I can decide which can be safely deleted?